# Control screen brightness in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is is possible to control the brightness of the screen on the WP7? The app I am making would be so much better if the user could change the brightness of the screen without having the leave the app.

No, this isn't a "flashlight" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to control this programatically with the current SDK.

The user has exclusive control over the brightness setting.